# pdf is not generated in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

right now i'm generate pdf using wkhtmltopdf gem.In development it is working fine.
if i'm run my project in production i got this error.already i'm install these two gems "wkhtmltopdf" & "wkhtmltopdf_binary".please help me.

RuntimeError (Failed to execute:
"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/wkhtmltopdf"  -q       - - 
Error: PDF could not be generated!):

Comment: did you try running the executable from a shell to check it is not corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

you can try by the following:

1. Uninstall the wkhtmltopdf package: sudo apt-get remove wkhtmltopdf --purge
2. (in usr/local/bin) sudo curl -C - -O http://wkhtmltopdf.googlecode.com/files/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2
3. (in usr/local/bin) sudo tar -xvjf wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-static-amd64.tar.bz2
4. (in usr/local/bin) ln -s wkhtmltopdf-amd64 wkhtmltopdf
5. In your initializer WickedPdf.config = { :exe_path => "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf" }

Note,you can get more wkhtmltopdf depend on your system: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/downloads/list

and you must remove the gem wkhtmltopdf_binary